# Power BI report builder / SSRS - highlight an individual datapoint on a bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, powerbi-paginated-reports

I've got the following dataset which represents the high low and average percentage scores for respondents in survey categories. The dataset also has a "Bar_Max" column set to 100 for all rows:

[image: dataset]

That I want to visualise like this:

[image]

I'm using a bar chart to try and do this.

I *think* that [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-data-points-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16) is telling me that I can do this with an expression in the colour property - so I tried this:

```
=Iif(Fields!Bar_Max.Value = Fields!MinPercentage.Value, "Red", "Green")
```

But that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Anyone know how to do this / know where I'm going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: In the expression you are saying that you want the color property to be Red if MinPercentage and Bar_Max are equal, elsewere you want the color to be Green. Is that what you want? Because the image shows something different

Comment: @Gam - no, the image is what I'm trying to get to, but the formula I'm trying is clearly not working. I'm trying to find a formula that will only colour the specific data point on the bar (corresponding to the min / max / average values) and leave the rest of the bar its normal colour.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've pretty much sorted this bar a bit of formatting.

Probably not the best way of doing it, but it seems to do the trick.

I decided to treat it as a stacked bar chart, where the min, average and max values = 1, and I basically calculate the value of the 'background' segments of the bar, then stack them together in order.

So I added some calculated columns to my dataset:
Fill1 is the first 'background' segment: `Min - Bar_Min`

Min = 1

Fill2 is the second 'background' segment: `Average - (Bar_Min + Min)`

Avg= 1

Fill3 is the third 'background' segment: `Max - (Average + Avg)`

Max = 1

Fill4 is the final 'background' segment: `Bar_Max - (Maximum + Max)`

Also had to tweak a couple of the above formulae to deal with the Maximum = 100, otherwise the segments add up to 101.

Which gives me this:

[image]

Then with that dataset in report builder, I create a stacked bar chart like this:

[image]

which is currently returning this:

[image]

So a bit of formatting / fine tuning, but largely there.

Cheers.